# How to detect language of smartphone user

Tags: locale, detection

For production of a set of mobilephone/ smartphone minisites, what do you recommend as a technology to automatically choose the language of the site:

- browser IP address
- mobile browser language request header
- any method related to device specifics or Carrier specifics of a certain country?
- any other method

The languages that will be targeted are:

- Vietnamese
- German
- Thai
- Arabic
- Spanish
- Indonesian
- Italian
- Japanese
- Chinese, both traditional/ Simplified
- Korean
- Russian

I understand the answers may vary per language, so feedback on all or any language would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This definitely belongs on StackOverflow and not here.

Answer (score 6):

Anything other that what a user has *specifically requested* is a bad idea. So, for example, using geographical IP lookup is a terrible idea. People may live in a country where multiple languages are spoken, or may simply prefer the *lingua franca* English, and might find it extremely annoying when another language is forced upon them.

Out of the options you mentioned only the browser language request header sounds like something a user might actually configure on his own. All other options I suspect will produce an inferior experience for large portions of the target audience.

Comment: Browser's language is a perfect choice as it's configurable by user and more importantly it's default is set by the phone's OS, so Japanese users on a Japanese phone are almost certain to be viewing through a japanese text browser unless they explicitly set it otherwise